# How to create a valid QgsVectorLayer from delimitedtext?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, standalone

I am having trouble loading csv files into layers using `QgsVectorLayer()`.

I know this looks like a repeat, but I have carefully read

[Create a script to add delimited text layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147435/create-a-script-to-add-delimited-text-layer-in-qgis)

and

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7491

but still cannot get it work.

An example of my data file, test.csv:

```
Index,y,x
0,37.7646618,-122.4960858
1,37.777494,-122.416311
2,37.717707,-122.3997056
3,37.732284,-122.498118
4,37.749998,-122.392333
```

My code:

```
import os
import urllib

import pathlib
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

local_path = 'C:\dev\FCMS_conflation\data\TMC_nodes.csv'
node_layer = 'test'

abspath = os.path.abspath(local_path)
params = {'delimiter': ',',
          'decimalPoint': '.',
          'xField': longitude,
          'yField': latitude}

uri = "%s?%s" %(pathlib.Path(abspath).as_uri(), urllib.unquote(urllib.urlencode(params)))

layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, node_layer, "delimitedtext")
```

The formatted URI looks like:

```
[] uri
>>> 'file:///C:/dev/FCMS_conflation/data/TMC_nodes.csv?decimalPoint=.&delimiter=,&xField=longitude&yField=latitude'
```

I have tried many variations of the parameters, including the `crs` and `type`. But no matter what I try, I cannot create a valid layer.

```
[] layer.isValid()
>>> False
```

I have verified that I can add the file using the QGIS gui. I even tried using the uri provided by `layer.metadata` from within the Python plugin.

I am using QGIS 2.10.1 on Windows 7 64-bit machine.

Comment: Good question, where does node_layer come from? It should be a Qstring but I can't see where it's being set. Are you getting any error message?

Comment: I defined node_layer to just be a random string. I edited the code snip. Maybe I need to make a Qstring?

Comment: No error messages. It just doesn't pass the isValid  test.

Comment: You're in python, QString is near enough to string (C would have a cow about the subtle difference). Perhaps it's the path that's the difficulty.. the example given doesn't start with file:///, perhaps just c:/dev...?decimal... like in the example.

Comment: It seems you need to set the QGIS prefix path, as I explain in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144058/how-to-load-a-raster-layer-using-pyqgis/146513#146513 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155745/failed-to-create-memory-layers-in-qgis-application-on-linux/155852#155852 Please let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: @gcarrillo Thanks for the solution! I had to work on another project for a while I just got back to this. For my Windows 7 machine I had to use:

`qgis_prefix = u'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you need to set the QGIS prefix path, as I explain in [Loading raster layer using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144058/how-to-load-a-raster-layer-using-pyqgis/146513#146513) and [Failed to create memory layers in QGIS application on Linux](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155745/failed-to-create-memory-layers-in-qgis-application-on-linux/155852#155852)