# Add spatial csv-layer in QGIS3.10 in a standalone script

Tags: pyqgis

I want to add a csv-layer by PyQGIS in a standalone script. This is my code:

```
uri = 'file:///C:/Users/sml/Desktop/point.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=x&yField=y'
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "point", "delimitedtext")
print(vlayer.isValid())
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

The same code works fine in the QGIS Python console, but it can't work in a standalone script. I don't know why.

Comment: It seems your question was already asked in GIS.SE. Does [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160353/how-to-create-a-valid-qgsvectorlayer-from-delimitedtext/163584#163584) work for you?

Comment: Thank you! That works! I didn't set my QGIS prefix path, that's the reason it didn't work.

Comment: Of course! I will do that!